# std::vector<std::vector<int>> push_back gives heap-buffer-overflow

Tags: c++, vector, clang, sanitizer

I am trying to solve hackerrank's [even tree task](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/even-tree) with the following piece of code to read the input (`std::cin` replaced with custom string data to have input and program code in one place here):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
  std::istringstream input( "10 9\n2 1\n3 1\n4 3\n5 2\n6 1\n7 2\n8 6\n9 8\n10 8\n");
  std::cin.rdbuf(input.rdbuf());

  int n,m;
  std::cin >> n >> m;

  std::vector<std::vector<int>> v(n);

  //std::vector<std::vector<int>> v(n, std::vector<int>(n, -1));

  int ui, vi;
  while (m--)
  {
    std::cin >> ui >> vi;
    v[ui].push_back(vi);
    v[vi].push_back(ui);
  }
}
```

The second number will be the number of edges ( subsequent number pairs ) so I can predict how many element in the vector I will need.

This code gives me the following sanitizer error (the same error with the commented line):

```
clang++-3.6 -g -Wall -fsanitize=address --std=c++11 main.cpp && ./a.out
=================================================================
==11606==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x611000009ff8 at pc 0x0000004e0beb bp 0x7ffd09cb9ab0 sp 0x7ffd09cb9aa8
READ of size 8 at 0x611000009ff8 thread T0
    #0 0x4e0bea  (PATH/a.out+0x4e0bea)
    #1 0x4dfa28  (PATH/a.out+0x4dfa28)
    #2 0x7f407bd75ec4  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21ec4)
    #3 0x438227  (PATH/a.out+0x438227)

0x611000009ff8 is located 8 bytes to the right of 240-byte region [0x611000009f00,0x611000009ff0)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x4de672  (PATH/a.out+0x4de672)
    #1 0x4ecf8a  (PATH/a.out+0x4ecf8a)
    #2 0x4eccd5  (PATH/a.out+0x4eccd5)
    #3 0x4eca90  (PATH/a.out+0x4eca90)
    #4 0x4ec70f  (PATH/a.out+0x4ec70f)
    #5 0x4ea89a  (PATH/a.out+0x4ea89a)
    #6 0x4e047a  (PATH/a.out+0x4e047a)
    #7 0x4df8f2  (PATH/a.out+0x4df8f2)
    #8 0x7f407bd75ec4  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21ec4)

Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c227fff93a0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c227fff93b0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c227fff93c0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c227fff93d0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c227fff93e0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x0c227fff93f0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 fa[fa]
  0x0c227fff9400: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c227fff9410: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c227fff9420: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c227fff9430: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c227fff9440: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Heap right redzone:      fb
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack partial redzone:   f4
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
==11606==ABORTING
```

What am I missing here?

**EDIT**

Ok so I have found one of the solutions which would be to `emplace_back` a default `std::vector<int>` on `v`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v(n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) v.emplace_back();
```

But why didn't it work before since constructor with `size_type` [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)

> 3) Constructs the container with count default-inserted instances of T. No copies are made.

Comment: `n = 10`, and you access `v[10]` (out of range) when reading line `10 8`. I didn't read the task you want to solve, but this sounds like an "off by one" error to me. Did you mean `v[ui-1]` and `v[vi-1]`?

Comment: You can try g++ compiler with -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG which will use safe containers with range checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v(n);
```

you create a vector with 10 elements, which means you can access elements with index [0,9] inclusive. In last data you have 10 8, that would lead to out of range access. If your data is in [1,10] range you need to adjust index:

```
v[ui-1].push_back(vi);
v[vi-1].push_back(ui);
```

PS your addition eliminates error because you create `std::vector` with 10 elements and then you add 10 elements more in the loop, which makes valid index [0,19]. You may fix your code by:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v(n+1);
```

without additional loop, if you want to use indexes in [1,10] interval (element with index 0 would still exists there though).

You may consider using `std::map<std::vector<int>>` and you do not have to worry about indexes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
  std::istringstream input( "10 9\n2 1\n3 1\n4 3\n5 2\n6 1\n7 2\n8 6\n9 8\n10 8\n");
  std::cin.rdbuf(input.rdbuf());

  int n,m;
  std::cin >> n >> m;

  std::map<std::vector<int>> v;

  int ui, vi;
  while (m--)
  {
    std::cin >> ui >> vi;
    v[ui].push_back(vi);
    v[vi].push_back(ui);
  }
}
```

in this case you will only have data with indexes you were used, but access to element by index will be significantly slower. You may also consider `std::unordered_map` for faster access, if you do not care if data is sorted inside container.